# Language anomaly. Curious jump

Tags: php

I have a section of code with the following structure.

```php
if ( isset( $x) ){
     error_log("A");
     $a = f();
     error_log("B");
}
error_log("C");
```

The error log has the entries

```
A
C
```

I get no other entries in the error log.

I have narrowed the odd behavior down to an API call, `phpCAS::isAuthenticated()`, phpCAS v1.3.2, inside f().

How is it possible for this code to skip the call to `error_log("B")`?  What language construct allows this?

Comment: There is no language construct that allows such operation. I guess you misinterpreted some debugging output.

Comment: Is there any other code, like catching exception, switch/loop with break, etc. Is is possible that the C log comes from somewhere else, e.g. execution is actually stopped before B, and another session or part of the code logs C?

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that `f()` doesn't cause control to jump back to *before* `isset($x)`, but on that pass `$x` is unset? This could happen with recursion, for example.

Comment: This is one of those cases where stack traces and step-through debugging trump log statements.

Comment: @Darhazer. No the C is the C shown, of that I am certain.

Comment: @kojiro, recursion is also a ruled out possibility.  There are log statements before the if.

Comment: OK, well, in the spirit of "whatever remains, however improbable", have you considered if `B` ends in a carriage return, but no newline?

Comment: @kojiro  I'm on that spiritual level too.  I added another log statment after B, that is not outputted either.

Comment: Can you look in `f()`? Can you dump a traceback inside it? Is step-through debugging out of the question?

Comment: @kojiro Step debugging is unfortunately unrealistic. Let me check the backtrace.

Comment: Kinda going out on a limb here, as I'm not terribly familiar with the internals of PHP and any locking that may go on, but given that `phpCAS::isAuthenticated()` actually makes use of `error_log()` (by calling `phpCAS::traceBegin()` and `phpCAS::traceEnd()` which then call `phpCAS::log()`), is it at all possible that your call to `error_log("B")` is not actually being skipped, but that the log is unable to complete the write due to still being "locked" by another function/process?

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes, this is the most likely answer. Now I just have to find out why C is in the output.

Comment: I would guess that whatever is preventing `B` from being written has completed and released control of the log file by the time you attempt to write `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your log 'C' is really this one ? You can log **FILE** and **LINE** if your error handler hasn't already this information.

If all three logs are really those ones, are you sure your code is really like that ? Don't you have some things before or after the call of f() ?

You may have some code which deactivate logs or change the handler, then reactivate or reset the old handler.
You can search strings like "set_error_handler", "ini_set", "error_log"...

If "f()" uses some classes instances, look at the contructor and destructor of their Class and not only in methods specificaly called.